# Calling data from https:// blob JSON url and displaying in Javascript webpage

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, blob

I am trying to take JSON data from an https:// blob url JSON file and display the data in a webpage using Javascript. The JSON Data is an array of objects (files with data and formatting).

As it stands, this is the code that I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
</head>
<body>
        <div id="myDiv"> 
                <image id="div" />
            </div>
        <head>
                <script> 
                    function toDataURL(url, callback) {
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.onload = function () {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onloadend = function () {
                                callback(reader.result);
                            }
                            reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
                        };
                        xhr.open('GET', url);
                        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                        xhr.send();
                    }

                    toDataURL('https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/xyz/xyz.json', function (dataUrl) { 
                        window.external.notify(dataUrl);
                        document.querySelector("#div").src = dataUrl;
                    })
                </script>

    </script>       


</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am not sure if this is the right path at all to retrieve data from an https:// blob. In addition, I am receiving the following two errors:

```
A cookie associated with a resource at http://localhost/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/xyz.json' from origin 'http://localhost:7000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have read about these errors and realize I can get around the cross domain error using an AJAX call and using "jsonp" as the type of data, however, am trying to avoid using an AJAX call at all if there is a the FileReader() method already build for blobs.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the term *blob JSON url* does not really exist. A *data URL* exists, but you really need to understand what a *data URL* is:

A *data URL* is not a traditional URL as you would understand it. Its a URL scheme that actually contains data as a BASE64 encoded string.

The next important thing is that `FileReader` is not a interface to work with data URLs or any URLs. The `FileReader` API is useful when you have a `File` reference. You usually get a `File` reference when the user selects or drops a file into your website. The important thing here is: `File` is a reference to a local file on the computer where the browser is opened. The `readAsDataURL` method of the `FileReader` API is used to convert a `File` to a data URL. This is useful when the user selects a file and you want to show a preview. Then you can use `readAsDataURL`. It will basically read that file, convert it to BASE64 and prepend something like `data:image/png;base64,` in case of a png image in front of t.

That being said `reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);` is not really a useful thing. If your url actually targets a image you can just do `<image id="div" src="http://example.com/your-image.png" />`. Or something like `document.querySelector("#div").src = yourUrl;`. You dont need the XMLHttpRequest.

However if your URL returns a JSON and inside the JSON is a data url (or a normal url) you just need to retreive that data url. And then you can do `document.querySelector("#div").src = yourUrl;`. But in that case you *need* to make an AJAX request.

Actually you *are* making an `AJAX` request. `XMLHttpRequest` *is* AJAX.

A short note about `jsonp`: Don't use it. It's a hack from a long time ago, you don't need it. What you're looking for is `CORS`. So yes, if you need to retrieve JSON from a different origin you need to use `CORS`. And you need to implement this on the server side. Not in your javascript.
However if your url is a direct `BLOB` url you dont need AJAX (and so `XMLHTttpRequest`.

A last note about `XMLHTttpRequest`: If you're trying to use modern APIs: avoid it. There is the much cleaner and better `fetch` API that you should use.